# Technical concepts of CASB Reverse Proxy

Tags: security, cloud, office365, reverse-proxy, microsoft365

Lately, I have been noticing a lot of blogs about CASB Reverse Proxy being used to route the traffic of a cloud application to improve security by parsing the traffic and applying various conditions to evaluate its risks.

I couldn't find any technical explanation related to this.

1. How can a cloud application like Office 365 or GSuite route its traffic through a proxy server? I do not see any configuration for this in these apps.
2. Assuming, I configure the proxy to point to a cloud application like Microsoft Teams. Whenever I access the proxy url, it proxies everything to Microsoft Teams. In my Reverse Proxy, I either get the url being accessed or the HTML content of the page being loaded. How can these be used to evaluate security risks? I couldn't find any docs in Office 365 or Gsuite regarding this.

**PS:** I'm not looking at any specific vendor. I'm just trying to learn the technical concepts. Any answers in context of Office 365 or Gsuite is appreciated because I have only those accounts and not any other cloud application.